# Ubuntu Software Center will not open

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center

When I attempt to open the Ubuntu Software center via terminal the following shows:

```
$ software-center
2015-03-03 13:07:01,990 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-03-03 13:07:02,224 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - building local database
2015-03-03 13:07:02,225 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 313, in __init__
    self._rebuild_and_reopen_local_db(pathname)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 532, in _rebuild_and_reopen_local_db
    rebuild_database(pathname, debian_sources, appstream_sources)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py", line 1148, in rebuild_database
    cache.open()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 155, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Type ‘WEW’ is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

I remember typing 'WEW' accidentally but I am not sure how to change this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a malformed line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` at line 3.

The best solution is to open that file with an editor an look for that line 3. Then you can comment the line out. Just add a `#`-character as first character of that line.

Then run `software-center` again.

Comment: The OP probably just needs to remove the string `WEW` from the 3rd line.

Comment: @chaos removed string WEW and now is failing in a different location:
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
xapian.DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't detect type of database

Comment: @koko then please post the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` in your question.